# Can I verify the integrity of an amazon instance?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

If my Amazon EC2 credentials are stolen at time `D`, can I verify the integrity of the root volume by:

1. Lookup the instance in EC2 API, check the time the primary network interface was attached, and use that as system creation time
2. Lookup the time the volume was attached
3. If the time the system was created is within 10 seconds of the time the root volume was attached, consider the system unmodified.

I'm assuming here that the instance was created before time `D`.

Another way to ask the question: This situation. I have an instance. I stop the instance. Someone steals (borrows) my AWS credentials, mounts the root volume of that instance to server B, modifies the root volume by adding their SSH key, and remounts it to the original server. How do I know the volume was modified before I boot the original server?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here? Have your credentials been compromised?

Comment: Can I trust a system I deployed is still that system even after my AWS credentials are compromised?

Comment: Not before you've done a complete audit of what actions were taken using those credentials.

Comment: Also, turn on two-factor authentication.

Comment: @EEAA 2-factor is on. Assume access secret and key were compromised despite best efforts to secure. CloudTrail is on. What would *you* look for to determine if the running instance was compromised that isn't indicated by the method described in the question?

Comment: Go through *all* of the cloudtrail logs with a fine-toothed comb. There's no shortcut here.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that you should be thorough, but that is not the question asked. If you're designing a system with AWS, I believe you need to assume your credentials will be stolen at least once, have a lot of triggers to identify the theft, and design your systems to be resilient. That is the heart of this question.

Comment: Hopefully this is not your root user?

Comment: For the sake of this question, assume it is root user, or an equivalent IAM user with policy at least to allow all on EC2 or IAM (where they can grant allow all on ec2).

Comment: Have you tried running `last` to see the last logins? That should provide you with a list of IP addresses. If those IP addresses look unusual to you, perhaps that's an indicator that someone else is using those stolen creds to access your instance.

Comment: Paul - I'd go to logs to see login activity but this question im looking for someone to find a fault with the proposed method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement security audit for your EC2 instances, consider using native Windows capabilities such as Security event log ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx )
in case of using Linux, you can install some trid party auditing tools ( https://cisofy.com/lynis/ )

If it show any suspicious activity such as logins from unknown locations, your instance is compromised.

Also it's recommended to limit an IP address range that can be used as a source IP address in order to connect to your instance. In this case, even if your key is stolen, it won't be possible to connect to your insance from anywhere except your network location.